# I don't understand this proof about graphs of cubic functions

Tags: functions, cubics

This [proof on proofs.wiki](http://proofs.wiki/All_graphs_of_cubic_functions_are_transformations_of_an_odd_cubic_function) shows that: All graphs of cubic functions are transformations of an odd cubic function.

I have no problems with the steps. I just do not understand what is the idea behing this proof.

Comment: The idea is just to show that changing the origin, the graph becomes a curve with symmetry with respect to the origin. In other words, a cubic curve has a centre of symmetry — which happens is the unique inflection point on the curve.

Answer (score 3):

Forget the linked proof. The idea is the following: All cubic graphs
$$\gamma:\quad y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\qquad=:f(x)\tag{1}$$
with $a\ne0$ have an inflection point $P:=(p,q)$ whose $x$-coordinate $p=-{b\over3a}$ is found by solving $f''(x)=6ax+2b=0$, and whose $y$-coordinate $q$ is then given by $q:=f(p)$.

We now introduce new coordinates $(\bar x,\bar y)$ whose origin is at $P$. This means that we put
$$x:=p+\bar x, \quad y:=q+\bar y$$
in $(1)$. After some calculation it turns out that in the new coordinates $\gamma$ appears as
$$\gamma:\quad \bar y=a\>\bar x^3+c'\bar x$$
with a certain new coefficient $c'$. This shows that any cubic graph is point-symmetric with repect to its inflection point.

Comment: Thank you, it is not too difficult after all.